# I have php client and i want to pass encrypted email string from PHP client to wcf service , which encryption technique is best?

Tags: c#, php, .net, wcf

I have php client and i want to pass encrypted email string from PHP client to wcf service , which encryption technique is best ?

What is best way to encrypt/decrypt data in uniform way ?

*There could be other client as well in future

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending some home-brewn encryption over plain `http`, you should use the standards that already exist, namely `https`.

Comment: https wont give fit in given situation, I am looking for encryption algorithm

Comment: As `https` *is* encryption, maybe you can add some detail about what your encryption needs to do *better* than https to fit your requirements.